# Impute missing years from known data

Tags: r, imputation

I have a dataset in r that looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
   FIPS GEOID        County_Name         sk09 skimp10 skimp11 skimp12 skimp13     sk2014 skimp15
  <int> <chr>              <chr>        <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1  1001 01001 Autauga County, AL -0.326729733      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.6310033      NA
2  1003 01003 Baldwin County, AL -0.422958353      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.5553960      NA
3  1005 01005 Barbour County, AL -1.196517104      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.8910361      NA
4  1007 01007    Bibb County, AL -0.951096825      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.9065815      NA
5  1009 01009  Blount County, AL -1.303935099      NA      NA      NA      NA -1.0132797      NA
6  1011 01011 Bullock County, AL  -0.10070437      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.5024002      NA
```

where each of my variables are a successive year (sk09 = 2009, skimp10 = 2010, skimp11 = 2011, etc.). I'm looking for a way to impute the variables for the years that I don't have based on the years that I do have. I've looked at the MICE package and the predict() function, but neither seems to be exactly what I'm seeking. Does this exist?

Comment: It looks like there are just two years that you have for each row. Are you looking for something more than linear interpolation?

Comment: No, I'd be happy with a simple linear data generation. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a simple linear interpolation like this:

```
SKdat$skimp10 = (4*SKdat$sk09  +   SKdat$sk2014)/5
SKdat$skimp11 = (3*SKdat$sk09  + 2*SKdat$sk2014)/5
SKdat$skimp12 = (2*SKdat$sk09  + 3*SKdat$sk2014)/5
SKdat$skimp13 = (SKdat$sk09    + 4*SKdat$sk2014)/5
SKdat$skimp15 = (-1*SKdat$sk09 + 6*SKdat$sk2014)/5
```

### Data

```
SKdat = read.table(text="FIPS GEOID        County_Name         sk09 skimp10 skimp11 skimp12 skimp13     sk2014 skimp15
1  1001 01001 'Autauga County, AL' -0.326729733      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.6310033      NA
2  1003 01003 'Baldwin County, AL' -0.422958353      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.5553960      NA
3  1005 01005 'Barbour County, AL' -1.196517104      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.8910361      NA
4  1007 01007    'Bibb County, AL' -0.951096825      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.9065815      NA
5  1009 01009  'Blount County, AL' -1.303935099      NA      NA      NA      NA -1.0132797      NA
6  1011 01011 'Bullock County, AL'  -0.10070437      NA      NA      NA      NA -0.5024002      NA",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for! Thank you so much - for whatever reason, I was having a really hard time visualizing the math.